# How to make this PHP function generate two random string instead of one?

Tags: php, function, tags

I was wondering if there is a way to make the following PHP function generate two different string instead of one?

```
function random_uuid( $length = 25 ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $uuid = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    return $uuid;
}

$uuid = random_uuid(25);
```

Comment: Yes, call the function once again maybe?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but I was hoping to make the function just generate two string instead of me calling it twice.

Comment: In PHP its best when function does exactly what it is supposed to do. So you already have this function which generates one string. Now you can put it into another function, which would call it twice and generate two strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP good practice is when function does exactly what it is supposed to do. So you already have one function:

```
function random_uuid( $length = 25 ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $uuid = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    return $uuid;
}
```

It perfectly does its job - generates random uuid. Now you can make another function, which will call this function twice:

```
function generate_two_strings($length) {
    return array(
        random_uuid($length),
        random_uuid($length)
    );
}

$result = generate_two_strings(15);

print_r($result);
```

**Best practices**:

- Function does its one and only job
- You split your code and keep functions small

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function random_uuid( $length = 25 ) {
$array=array();
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$uuid1 = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    array_push($array,$uuid1);
$uuid2 = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
    array_push($array,$uuid2);
return $array;
}
$stuff = random_uuid();
var_dump($stuff);
```

Maybe?